# Setting LDAP users Permission and assigning roles on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: server

I want to create users and want to give the permissions to change the password after first login, pr user cannot change their password like this permissions i want to assign. 
Is there any application for this through which i can get all the features which i want.

Answer (score 0):

There are no straight answer for this, you need to combined LDAP with PAM.D module to make it work. Another solution would be IdM server for Red Hat.

Comment: Can you please elaborate or share the procedures if you have . or refer me any link , it would be very much helpful for me if you can share.

Thank You for your response.